# Help with regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I am converting some associative array database calls to object orientated results. So I would love a reg exp I can use in find and replace to convert :

`$rsName['fieldName']` to `$rsName->fieldName`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/\$rsName\[\'(.*?)\'\]/', '$rsName->$1', $str);
```

Also, this won't take into account escaped `'` in the key string.

How do you intend to run this? `eval()`? Bad idea, if so.

This also assumes that `$rsName` is a constant.

[See it on CodePad.org](http://codepad.org/lLFpPazj).

Comment: Thanks Alex will give it a go. Intend on running in in textmate to convert the code.